# Как вытянуть картинку и текстовый блок за границы контейнера используя только HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

B HTML код должен выглядеть следующим образом

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="text-box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И с помощью css вытянуть картинку за контейнер, так что бы она принимала ширину и высоту блока родителя

Comment: покажите скрин с версткой (через f12), чтобы было видно блок, в который вы хотите вписать картинку

Comment: В чем сакральный смысл нарушения стандартов верстки? 
Что мешает просто построить правильную последовательность блоков?
+ к коменту MaximLensky

Comment: https://imgur.com/DTqlW4D (блок с вёрсткой).
Контейнер нужен для следующего, если вы посмотрите картинку в посте, это макет, линиями обозначен контейнер. И весть контент в правом блоке должен быть в этом контейнере, но только в пределах блока, не залазить на картинку

Comment: в вашей же верстке задайте классу image ширину 50% и классу .text-box тоже.
от контейнера вообще можно избиваться, если он не несет реальной структурной логики в себе

Comment: @MaximLensky, я понимаю, в этом и суть вопроса, я два блока помещаю в контейнер, который ограничен по ширине и отцентрирован, и мне нужно картинку вытащить за границы контейнера и сделать что бы она занимала 50% ширины экрана, т.е. 50vw

Comment: вы так и не объяснили зачем вам контейнер в этой картине.
Такая верстка реализуется иначе

Comment: @Константин, что бы текст оставался в пределах контейнера

Comment: <div class="section">

        <div class="image"></div>
    
        <div class="text-box"></div>

</div>

<style type="text/css">
.image{
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
}

.text-block{
width:50%;
padding-right:20%;    
}
</style>
Такая верстка даст визуальный результат как на скрине

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/v8Oi3ew я постарался объяснить,
данный контейнер находится в каждом блоке на странице,
https://imgur.com/a/gYUClK9
структура блоков сайта следующая
блок родитель - контейнер - контент
суть такой структуры, в том что бы давать главному блоку background и он будет на 100% экрана а не в пределах контейнера

Comment: @MaximLensky, куда вам залить что бы вы увидели?

Comment: @MaximLensky вот решение, сделал

Answer (score 0):

К контейнеру добавьте ваши стили центровки

```
     <div class="section">

        <div class="image"></div>

        <div class="text-box"></div>


        <div class='container'>
            некий текст
        </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.image{
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
}

.text-box{
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
padding-right:20%;
background-color: orange;    
}

.container{
    padding-left: 60%;
    padding-top:10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="about-us">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image"><img src="images/about-us-bg.jpg" alt="School items"></div>
            <div class="text-box">
                <h2>ABout us</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Задаём следующие стили

```
.about-us {
  background: #ffc155;

  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    .image {
      flex-basis: 50vw;
      min-width: 50vw;

      img {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    }

    .text-box {
      flex-basis: 50%;
      min-width: 50%;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Смотри в общем: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/GRJmJrB  если что не ясно спроси - я помогу

Comment: @MaximLensky, посмотри мой код, я в ответ прикрепил, всё работает, ты поймёшь как я хотел сделать)

Comment: я же предлогал это уже ...